# Component not appearing in Tkinter Python interface

Tags: python, tkinter, interface

I just start developping in Python to do some interface with Tkinter.
There is so many way to do an interface, so I would like to know if the structure of my code is correct.
Also, I can run my script without error. But, it didn't show me the label ,Hello, world".

Can you explain me what is wrong ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# import 
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        # Definition of the main window
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.geometry("800x800")
        self.master.title("Test application")


    label = Label(self, text="Hello, world")
    label.pack()

def quit(self):
    sys.exit()


# ACTION
def load_file(self) :
    filename=askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Input files", "*.igs")))
    if filename :
        try:
            print("""here it comes: self.settings["template"].set(filename)""")
        except:                     # <- naked except is a bad idea
            showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
        return


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Frame (`class MyFrame`) is never packed. Use `self.pack()` inside your init to display it or pack it inside your main before calling mainloop on it.

The rest looks okay so far.

As you are using tkinter (so python3) i personally would consider using

`"some text {}".format(variable)`

over `"some text %s"%variable` whenever possible.